# How to fix error when looking for child in firebase database (Swift)?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save items to a Firebase database under a child taken from a text field. I haven't got to that yet though, I am still trying to work out how to check if a value already exists. Here is my code...

```
@objc func submitNote() {
    print("Attempting to save or update note")

    //Check if file exists
    if name != nil && text != nil {
        //Access database
        var ref: DatabaseReference!
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("lists").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChild(self.name!){
                print("true")
                //Update

                return
            } else {
                print("false")
                //Create
                self.uploadNew()
            }
        })
        return
    } else {
        print("Error")
        return
    }
}
```

It has to be an @objc function as it is run using #selector in a menu bar. As you can see it checks to make sure the text fields aren't empty. Here are the variables...

```
public var name: String?
public var text: String?
```

Which are set inside separate functions...

```
name = titleText.text
text = textView.text
```

The reason I have set the variables this way is because I am creating the view programically and both individual text views/fields are  set inside functions so I don't think I can access them from the submitNote function. Anyway the error I'm getting it this...

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(hasChild:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''
```

I have checked and triple checked but there aren't any of those values in the text fields and even though the if statement is meant to stop the app continuing unless they are not equal to nil I tried with text in the fields but no matter what if I press the button to run this function I get the same error. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: The code in this question will retrieve the /lists node and all of it's child nodes - that may be unnecessary if you are looking to see if a `/lists/some_name' .exists() (hint hint). We would need to see a snippet of your structure to really understand what you are trying to do. Can you update your question with that, as text please, no images, and we can probably help.

Answer (score 0):

You only check if `name` is not null but not if it is empty ("")

```
  if let value = self.name, !value.isEmpty...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Firebase structure was not included in the question so I'll make one up for you

```
lists
   Leroy: true
   Billy: true
   James: true
```

now some code to see if a name exists in the lists node. We're using snapshot.exists to see if any data was returned in the snapshot.

```
func doesNameExistInLists(name: String) {
    let ref = self.ref.child("lists").child(name)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print("found it")
        } else {
            print("name not found")
        }
    })
}
```

then when it's called, here are the results

```
self.doesNameExistInLists(name: "Billy")
```

console: found it

```
self.doesNameExistInLists(name: "aaaa")
```

console: name not found